# Initialize Vue Formulate with Async Data from API

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuex, vue-formulate

I am trying to initialize a Vue Formulate Form with some user data that I get from an API via axios inside a Vuex Store in Nuxt. I am using Vue Mapstate to get the store state inside the computed data. The async data is not resolved initially and it seems that the :values property from Vue Formulate is not reacting after a successful response. Is it possible to create a data property that initializes with the asnyc data that I fetch from the API in my component?

Comment: What did you tried so far? Can you show us some code please?

Comment: Thanks, I got it working using v-model that reacts to the async changes! :-)